# ping with line numbers

Tags: linux, ping

Simple question:  how to make `ping` on Linux to show line numbers in output?

I mean:

```
1 64 bytes from www.site.com (2.7.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=247 time=17.9 ms
2 64 bytes from www.site.com (2.7.1.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=247 time=16.1 ms
3 64 bytes from www.site.com (2.7.1.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=247 time=16.1 ms
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`nl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/nl.1.html) command adds line numbers to its input, so you can pipe the output of `ping` to `nl`.

```
% ping -c3 google.com | nl
     1  PING google.com (74.125.224.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
     2  64 bytes from nuq04s08-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.224.105): icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=31.2 ms
     3  64 bytes from nuq04s08-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.224.105): icmp_req=2 ttl=55 time=14.8 ms
     4  64 bytes from nuq04s08-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.224.105): icmp_req=3 ttl=55 time=16.3 ms

     5  --- google.com ping statistics ---
     6  3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
     7  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.851/20.833/31.286/7.417 ms
```

Comment: Wow, cool. Didn't know of `nl` previously.

Comment: @ErikA Yup, it's even part of POSIX.

Comment: ... and after all these years I learn about `nl`. Apparently it also has other meanings than Dutch TLD. +1 to you, Sir!

Comment: nl, now fancy that .. +1 for a cmd i never knew about